# one input text value change base on another one's (jquery autocomplete) value (Classic ASP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, asp-classic, jquery-autocomplete

i have this jquery autocomplete works perfectly: (let say, input text name is "item description", these names are pull from a SQL database)

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"Apple",
"Banana",
"Mouse"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

And now i have to add a price input text field next to it.

now i can think of is, populates a list of price (from SQL database) and fill the price in accordingly base on which item is selected from the autocompleted field.

but how? any ideas?

Comment: Would a simple two dimensional array and onChnage on #tags to changes #price work?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#Article1C").autocomplete({
         source: function( request, response ) {
                              $.getJSON( "/inc/Autocomplete/ajaxAutocompleteArticle.asp",
                                         { term: request.term,
                                           rows : 16 },
                                           response );
                 },
         minLength: 2,
                 select: function( event, ui ) {
                 if (ui.item) {
                                        $("#ArticleID").val(ui.item.aid);
                                  }
                                }

  });
```

/inc/Autocomplete/ajaxAutocompleteArticle.asp

something like this

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<% Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<!--#include virtual="/Connections/connection.asp" -->
<%
rsCusts__MMRowsParam = 20:   if Request.QueryString("rows") <> "" then  rsCusts__MMRowsParam = CLNG(Request.QueryString("rows"))

If (Request.QueryString("term") <> "") Then 
  rsCusts__MMColParam = Request.QueryString("term")     
End If
%>
<%
sOrderrsCusts =  " ORDER By Descr1 ASC " 
sWherersCusts  = "  where not costID is null"
sWhere  = " AND "

if rsCusts__MMColParam <> "" then 
    Iterator = split(rsCusts__MMColParam," ")
   for i = LBOUND( Iterator ) to UBOUND(Iterator)
    k = Instr(Iterator(i),"-")
    if k = 1 then
        sWherersCusts = sWherersCusts & sWhere & " convert(nvarchar(6),ID) +' '+ Descr1 NOT LIKE '%" & MID(Iterator(i),k+1,LEN(Iterator(i))) & "%'"
      else
        sWherersCusts = sWherersCusts & sWhere & " convert(nvarchar(6),ID) +' '+ Descr1 LIKE '%" & Iterator(i) & "%'"   
    end if
      sWhere = " AND "  
   NEXT
else
    sWherersCusts = " not costID is null "
end if
%>
<%
Dim rsCusts
Dim rsCusts_cmd
Dim rsCusts_numRows

Set rsCusts_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsCusts_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_connection_STRING
rsCusts_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP "&rsCusts__MMRowsParam&" [ID] ,AID = CostID, ArticleName = convert(nvarchar(6),ID) +' '+ Descr1 FROM [CostItems]" & sWherersCusts & sOrderrsCusts
rsCusts_cmd.CommandType = 1
rsCusts_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsCusts = rsCusts_cmd.Execute
rsCusts_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim Repeat1__numRows
Dim Repeat1__index

Repeat1__numRows = -1
Repeat1__index = 0

rsCusts_numRows = rsCusts_numRows + Repeat1__numRows

Response.Write "["
Comma = ""

While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsCusts.EOF)) 

    Response.Write  Comma & "{""id"":"""&(rsCusts.Fields.Item("ID").Value)&""", ""label"":""" &  (rsCusts.Fields.Item("ArticleName").Value)&""", ""value"":""" & (rsCusts.Fields.Item("ID").Value)&""", ""aid"":""" & (rsCusts.Fields.Item("AID").Value)&""" } "  
    Comma = ","

  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  rsCusts.MoveNext()
Wend

Response.Write "]"


%>


<%
rsCusts.Close()
Set rsCusts = Nothing
%>
```